# Should Odata(V4) actions be invoked only with POST?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

Odata V4 Spec says that Actions MAY have observable side effects and should be invoked using HTTP POST. But we do have scenarios where we need to use actions which just modifies some status.

For example : 
1.
You might want to mark status of a document identified by a id as locked
 Endpoint - .../Documents({id})/lock(). 
 Since I am doing a partial update here, In my opinion PATCH is more suitable.
2.
 You might want to offer two ways of deleting a document
 a) Just Hide 
Endpoint - ...../Documents({id}) 
 This is with HTTP DELETE (no disputes)
 b) Delete Permanently
Endpoint - ...../Documents({id})/permanentDelete() 
This as an ODATA action.
 In my opinion, HTTP Delete would be more appropriate here instead of HTTP POST.

What is the recommended way to do this from Odata standpoint? Any help here is much appreciated.

Below is the information from SPEC.

**SPEC**
**11.5.4 Actions**

Actions are operations exposed by an OData service that MAY have side effects when invoked. Actions MAY return data but MUST NOT be further composed with additional path segments.
**11.5.4.1 Invoking an Action**

To invoke an action bound to a resource, the client issues a **POST** request to an action URL. An action URL may be obtained from a previously returned entity representation or constructed by appending the namespace- or alias-qualified action name to a URL that identifies a resource whose type is the same as, or derives from, the type of the binding parameter of the action. The value for the binding parameter is the value of the resource identified by the URL prior to appending the action name, and any non-binding parameter values are passed in the request body according to the particular format.

Thanks in advance
--ksp

Answer (score 2):

From an OData standpoint, you always have to invoke an action with a POST, with any other verb, it won't work.

Both of your examples are things that I personally don't think are well suited to an action as there are already ways to do these things with OData and they use the verbs that you are mentioning.Updating a property is supported with a PATCH and deleting an object is supported with a DELETE. You mention that you have two different types of delete operations, this is more difficult but you could use a custom header to distinguish between them.

An action tends to be something that doesn't fit into the normal CRUD operations so it isn't always clear which HTTP verb should be used for this.

In your examples, it does *feel* right to want to use DELETE and PATCH. However, the problem comes because we need to have a standard to follow, bear in mind that OData actions are all discoverable through the metadata so could be consumed by a client with no knowledge of what the actions actually do and in this case, we need to have something defined. Since we know that actions affect the server in some way, to me, it seems like POST is the least bad option that is consistent for all actions.

Comment: But the latest implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.OData doesn't seem to work well with the POST verb when the action takes no parameters.

Comment: @Eniola POST is probably the most common verb used in OData, i've never experienced any issues with actions that have no parameters, they are great for toggling flags or for other process logic. I have many actions like `StartNow()`, `CheckIn()`, `CheckOut()`. I reaslize this is an old comment but if you are experiencing issues please link in a reference or post your own question so we can get you back up and running. Often 3rd party components like _Swashbuckle_ can cause problems with empty parameters, but there are quick fixes for those components, the issue is NOT in the OData runtime

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, thanks for this. At the time I was just wrapping my head around the ASP.NET Core implementation of OData and I got a number of things in a twist. One suggestion I have though. Why do all parameters coming into an action have to be read from a ODataParameters Dictionary? Why not allow us use a [FromBody] parameter that maps to the elements in the HTTP message body so that the validation done behind the scenes by OData is more readable/discoverable in the implementing method and strongly typed from the get go.

Comment: @Eniola I can'tsay for sure, except that from a design point of view, using `[FromBody]` only works if the entire body is a single object, _or_ a single type. A key tenent in OData is to reduce the ambiguity, everything must be formally defined in the metadata model, there is no 'or' in the definitions. While I remember having the same issues when starting out, I really thought I wanted typed parameter access, however this would have meant that for almost every request I could have a unique class definition, which becomes a lot of redundant types to manage

Comment: Supporting optional parameters or enforcing only some parameters as required becomes problematic with a class representation, treating the inputs as an array of keyed values gets around the redundant class definitions and gives us some flexibility that is hard to express in serialization scenarios used in other implementations that do use `[FromBody]`. For me, I quickly identified this is a powerful feature but one that is too volatile to leave to just anyone in the team to add their own endpoints, more often than not they were using the wrong syntax or expectations.

Comment: My OData controllers are now 100% generated using T4 templates, we write extension methods against the EF model types, OData is simply a REST wrapper around that. In the end this was the easiest way to package the definition and the implementation of the endpoints, so now I don't need to interpret the input parameters, I'm inspecting the method that needs to be executed and generating the meta data from that. I'm not sure that out of the box OData is the easiest toolset to get going with, but I've found that in using it my team has become far more productive.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, as the author, your API is yours to command. Just as we *shouldn't* use properties in C# class design that cause side affects in other properties, that doesn't mean we cant, and it can be pretty common.

> From an OData standpoint, `PATCH` is analogous to using property accessors and *actions* or `POST` is for accessing methods.

Making the decision between `PATCH` or `POST` to affect change is therefor the same design decision between using property *mutators* (making them writable) or forcing the caller to set their values through related *methods*.

> 1. You might want to mark status of a document identified by a id as locked
>    Endpoint - .../Documents({id})/lock().
>    Since I am doing a partial update here, In my opinion PATCH is more suitable.

If your resource has a *property* called `Locked`, and your current `lock()` *Action* only  sets the `Locked` property to `true`, then you *could* simply use `PATCH` to update just that `Locked` field.

Some common reasons to use an *Action* specifically for a *lock* process:

1. You want to execute specific logic when `lock()` is called and you want to maintain this logic in it's own method, rather than having complex conditional logic inside your patch handler.
2. You don't want the reverse logic, `unlock()` to be available to *everyone*, when a resource is *locked*, presumably only the user who locked it can release the lock or other conditions need to be satisfied.

   - as with the first point, this sort of logic is generally easier to maintain in its own method, and therefore *Action*.
3. You want to use Security Attributes to restrict access to `lock()` to certain security groups, yet you want all users to have read access the the `Locked` state field.
4. When a resource is *locked* other fields are also set, like `LockedBy` and perhaps `DateLocked`.

While all of that logic *could* be managed in your single `PATCH` endpoint logic for the controller, I can't stress enough how this can easily make your solution unmanageable over time or as the complexity of your resource increases.

**More importantly:** the documented and accepted convention is that `PATCH` will *NOT* have side effects, and as such there is no need to execute a `GET` after a `PATCH` because the same change on the client has been accepted on the server. Conversely, because a `POST` *MAY* have side effects, it is reasonable for the client to expect to execute a `GET` to get all the related changes if the response from the `POST` does not contain the updated resource.

In the case of `Delete` vs `PermanentlyDelete` now things become personal / opinionated...
By convention, the expectation of `DELETE` is two fold:

1. After a delete the resource should no longer appear in collection query results from a `GET`
2. After a delete the resource should no longer appear in item requests via `GET`

From a server point of view, if my resource has a *soft* delete, that simply sets a flag, and a *permanent* delete that deletes the record from the underlying store, then by convention I would use an `Action` called `Delete()` for the *soft* delete, and the *permanent* delete should use the `DELETE` http verb.

- The general reasoning for this is the same as for the discussion about `locked()`.

However, if the intention of *soft* vs *permanent* delete is to intercept the client's standard delete workflow, such that the permanent delete concept is hidden or otherwise abstracted in a way that it is not part of the usual workflow (the user has to go somewhere different, like the *recycle bin* to view deleted records and restore or permanently delete), in that scenario, use the HTTP verb `DELETE` for soft delete, and make a specific, perhaps collection bound *Action* to accept the request for permanent delete

- This action may have to be unbound, or bound to the collection depending on how you implement your filtering, if we have deleted record 'xyz' such the `GET: ~/document('xyz')` returns `NOT-FOUND` then we can't really expect `POST: ~/document('xyz')/delete()` to execute...